# Animation in jQuery works on desktop but not in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have an animation that triggers when the page load and it is an image going from right to left, very straightforward. Now, it works very well on desktop but not so good in mobile. Is there any way to apply something like a media queries as it is done with css but for jQuery?

Comment: You should include your code and a "Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example": https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You can actually try to combine CSS media queries and JS, by using a hidden element and setting a specific value for some CSS property like z-index. You can then check the value of this property with JS and set a mobile variable accordingly.

I've found that this works more accurate than trying to get the viewport width in JS. Or at least it makes sure that the point at which the variable is true in JS is exactly the same as when the changes to the CSS occur.

**CSS**

```
#test {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #test {
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
(function($) {

  var $test,
      isMobile = false;

  function checkTest() {
    if ($test.length) {
      isMobile = $test.css('z-index')=='2';
    }
  }

  $(function() {
    $test = $('#test');
    checkTest();
  });

  $(window).on('resize',function() {
    checkTest();    
  });

  // in the rest of your code you can now simply check if isMobile is true

})(jQuery);
```

**Edit**
Preferably you should not be using an extra hidden element just for this purpose. You should usually have some existing element that is altered in some way by the media query and you can check for that. Like a header that is fixed in desktop view but not for mobile, or perhaps a logo that is 200px wide for desktop and only 100px for mobile. You get the idea.